# count number of times a string appears in a text file using script

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I need to write a .bat or .cmd script that will find all instances of file type .log in the directory it is run from, and for each of those search it for "*searchstring*", counting how many times it appears.  Then I need to rename the file (original name: "[name].log") to "name.log".  This is to enable me to get a very quick visual count of the number of errors in a file (which is part of what the log contains).

I've already got the for loop that locates all *.log files, but how do I count instances of a particular string?

Comment: `find /c` should help you

Comment: Your rename requirement doesn't make any sense. Did you mean something like "[name].log" becomes "[name]_[count].log" ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for /f "tokens=2delims=:" %a in ('find /c "string" *.log') do @set /a count+=%a
echo %count%
```

Code is for shell prompt. For shell file replace `%a` with `%%a`.